# Between steps for fisher information matrix element using Poisson regression?

Tags: expected-value, poisson-regression, fisher-information, scoring-rules

I am currently working through some math related to my work, and trying to understand how the individual pieces of the following equations come together for the Fisher information matrix expression (Eq. 8). I attached part of the document it comes from, but will attach formulas at the bottom as well. From what I understand, Eq. 7 can be further broken down into:

$\ln(L(x\mid\theta)) = \sum_k (x_k - \mu_k + x_k \ln(\mu_k) - x_k \ln(x_k))$

... if "$\ln(x!) = x \ln (x) - x$" is used.

From here though, I am unsure how to get to Eq. 8 via partial derivation.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated!

---

[image: Eq. 6: I_i,j(θ) = E(((Ln(L(X|θ)))/δθ_i) ((Ln(L(X|θ)))/δθ_j)) ... where θ is a set of parameters being estimated, L(X|θ) is the likelihood of data set X given a model generated by θ, and μ is an imaging model using Eq. 7: L(X|θ)) = ProductSeries_k (((μ_k)^x_k e^(-μ_k))/(x_k)! Eq. 8: I_i,j(θ) = E (Sum_k ((x_k - μ_k)^2 (1/(μ_k)^2) (δ(μ_k)/δθ_i) (δ(μ_k)/δθ_j)) ) Eq. 9: I_i,j(θ) = Sum_k ((1/(μ_k)^2) (δ(μ_k)/δθ_i) (δ(μ_k)/δθ_j))]

---

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Welcome to CV. This is a MathJax-enabled site. Please use it to render your equations in $\LaTeX$ for better readability.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have edited your question and removed the formulae that you copied from the text, because some important information got lost in that process and they thus contribute to confusion ;-). I just learned that certain questions are better for mathematics.SE and will vote for migration there - you are also a user on that site, so no harm is done, and they have a lot of similar questions clarifying how to get from eqn (x) to eqn (x+1)

Comment: Thank you for the edit Ute! I will then see if I can migrate the question maybe, haha.

Comment: I believe I do, but I've not been able to work this one out yet. From looking at the equations, it looks like you could work backwards somewhat from Eq.8 since you know what you would get, but I can't quite get the steps involved.

Comment: If you are happy with what I tried below, we can also forget about all that migration :-). Let me know if it makes sense to you or if you need further help. Where is the original text? A book?

Comment: I am excited but still not quite getting it, haha. Thanks so much for attempting this. The original text is a paper on super resolution microscopy. doi:10.1038/nmeth.1449

Comment: Oh wait. Yeah I overlooked something wow. I think you got it + I get it!

Comment: Thank you for the reference, super resolution microscopy. doi:10.1038/nmeth.1449 - amazing! I had my last PhD student working on a model for single molecule localization microscopy. What a coincidence :-)

Comment: Nice coincidence indeed! :) I love the topic but sadly my math is a bit rusty, so I'm trying to quickly catch up to where I can read the papers properly. If all goes well, I'll be starting my PhD project on something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how the Stirling approximation comes in...
If you take it directly from Eqn. (7),
$$
  \ln(L(x\mid\theta))=\sum_k [x_k\ln(\mu_k) -\mu_k -\ln(x_k!)]
$$
thus
$$
  \frac{\partial\ln(L(x\mid\theta))}{\partial\theta_i}=\sum_k[ x_k\frac{1}{\mu_k}\frac{\partial \mu_k}{\partial\theta_i} -\frac{\partial\mu_k}{\partial\theta_i} -0]=\sum_k \frac{x_k-\mu_k}{\mu_k}\frac{\partial \mu_k}{\partial\theta_i}.
$$
In order to get Eqn. (8) from there, we need some independence assumption for $x_k$ and $x_{k^\prime}$ that gives us, for $k^\prime\neq k$, that
$$
E[(x_k-\mu_k)(x_{k^\prime}-\mu_{k^\prime})]=0.
$$